# Entity Framework 5 Cascade Deletes not working Despite Proper Config

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have two tables in a parent>child relationship.

Upon attempting to delete the parent, I am getting the following error:

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 in a dbfirst type model.

In the database, the delete rule is set to cascade, and I double checked that in the .edmx that rule is also set to cascade.

I am using doing multiple transactions and then calling .SaveChanges() at the end...not sure if that has anything to do with it. Specifically there is an update that I am issuing on another table first, then this delete.

Here is my common repository code for delete:

```
public virtual ActionConfirmation<int> Delete(TRepository entity, bool boolCommitChgs = true)
        {

            try
            {   
                //DbSet.Remove(entity);
                _dataContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
                if (boolCommitChgs)
                {
                    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
                }

                return CRUDMessage(true, "deleted", entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return CRUDMessage(false, "delete", entity, ex);
            }
        }
```

And then I complete the transaction and call SaveChanges here, which is when the error is thrown:

```
try
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            result = ActionConfirmation<int>.CreateSuccessConfirmation(
                            string.Format("{0} {1}: {2} successful.",
                            strNoun,
                            id, 
                            strVerb
                        ),
                            id
                        );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          ....etc....
```

Any ideas why I'd be getting this error?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah...a bit closer to narrowing in on it...id does have to do with grouping of multiple updates in the same transaction. If I just issue a delete of the parent and call SaveChanges directly afterward, it works...so for some reason, you can't do an update on another table and then issue the delete on this unrelated table???

Comment: The issue can be caused by your updates changing some relations.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav for the suggestion...but I don't think this is the case. If I attempt to alter 2 tables, that have not relationship, but using the same context, it gives me that error. If I use a new instance of the context for each table modification, it works. So maybe I don't understand the DbContext, but I'd think you'd be able to update table X and then delete table Y within the same DbContext instance without issue. Again, there is absolutely no relationship between table x and table y....confused :(

Comment: Ah, you were correct @Ladislav. I was first reading one table to determine which entries to delete in a second...since those 2 tables have no dependencies on one another, I didn't understand why there was an issue..BUT...then I was trying to go back and delete a row in a table that was the parent to the first. This is what was causing the error, I believe, because the context was already tracking these children rows. So I'm guessing you could detach these entities first, the proceed with the parent record delete. But for now, I've just used one context to read and another to delete.

Comment: Ladislav, if you put your comment as an answer, I will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be caused by your updates changing some relations.